# Configuring mail command to use msmtp

Tags: mail-command, msmtp

msmtp is successfully installed and works fine to send emails via an external SMTP server.

However the mail command fails to send emails using *GNU Mailutils* on a Debian 10.

for example

```
echo "Test" | mail personal@external.email
```

returns

```
mail: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status
```

and

```
echo $?
```

returns "36"

I'm supposing this is a msmtp is not integrating with the mail command. How do I configure mail to send messages through msmtp?

EDIT: The programs seem to be communicating because the keyring prompt pops up and the login options are set only in ~/.msmtprc

Comment: There are different software packages offering a mail command. Can you please add information about which one you are using.

Comment: @MathiasWeidner Wasn't aware, thanks for calling out. It's GNU Mailutils. Edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

This worked

From https://moritzvd.com/email-with-smtp-debian-ubuntu/

In order to be able to use the mail command wee need to install mailx

`sudo apt-get install bsd-mailx`

Set mail transport agent to use msmtp

`sudo nano /etc/mail.rc`

append the following:

`set mta=/usr/bin/msmtp`

Comment: Thanks, I tried installing `s-nail` which still didn't provide the `mail` command.  Your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to configure the `mailer` statement in the config file as is [explained in the manual](https://mailutils.org/manual/html_node/mailer-statement.html). Either use a statement like `sendmail://progname` if msmtp adheres to sendmail compatibility or use something like `prog://pathname[?query]` as is explained [on this page](https://mailutils.org/manual/html_node/Program-Mailboxes.html).

How you can find the global or local config file is also [explained in the manual](https://mailutils.org/manual/html_node/configuration.html). It is usually */etc/mailutils.config* for the global config file or *~/.mail* for the local config file.

Comment: Config files are to be found nowhere. The commands in the manual do not return any results, and they are not on the suggested locations. The programs seem to be communicating because the keyring prompt pops up and the login options are set only in ~/.msmtprc  Editing question again. Could not find the log files either.

Comment: edit: The log files are there but show no update once I removed postfix (it was overkill for this project).

Comment: It might be an issue with msmtp-mta, but it's hard to find documentation on that. https://wiki.debian.org/msmtp

Comment: You can look with `strings $(which mail)` what filename is compiled in. On an Ubuntu 18.04 I am using, the local config file seems to be *~/.mailrc*.

Comment: This worked
From
https://moritzvd.com/email-with-smtp-debian-ubuntu/

In order to be able to use the mail command wee need to install mailx

sudo apt-get install bsd-mailx

Set mail transport agent to use msmtp

sudo nano /etc/mail.rc

append the following:

set mta=/usr/bin/msmtp

Comment: I didn't want to install other programs, so I was able to figure it out. If it doesn't exist already create `/etc/mailutils.conf` then add the following line.
`mailer {
  url "sendmail:///usr/bin/msmtp";
}`